# Recursion with Maybe

Tags: haskell, recursion, immutability

I'm having difficulty try to write a function to find the sum of two lists using recursion, that possibly could be Nothing if any list is empty.

The math of the following functions are:

```
Σw[i]x[i]
```

where w and x are equal length int arrays

Here is my working code:

```
example :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Int
example [] [] = 0
example (x:xs) (l:ls) = ((x*l) + (example xs ls))
```

Here is the idea of what I want to work:

```
example :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Maybe Int
example [] [] = Nothing
example (x:xs) (l:ls) = Just((x*l) + (example xs ls))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing at what your intent is here, not sure whether I read it correctly: You want the function to produce `Nothing` when the two input lists have difference lengths?

The "happy" base case is `0` just like in the first attempt, but lifted into `Maybe`.

```
example [] [] = Just 0
```

To handle situations where the lists have different lengths, include the cases where only *one* of the lists is empty. You should have gotten a compiler warning about a non-exhaustive pattern match for not including these cases.

```
example [] _ = Nothing
example _ [] = Nothing
```

The final case, then, is where you have two nonempty lists. It looks a lot like that line from your first attempt, except rather than applying the addition directly to `example xs ys`, we **`fmap`** the addition over `example xs ys`, taking advantage of the fact that `Maybe` is a [`Functor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Functor.html).

```
example (x : xs) (y : ys) = fmap (x * y +) (example xs ys)
```

Example usage:

```
λ> example [1,2] [3,4]
Just 11

λ> example [1,2] [3,4,5]
Nothing
```

By the way, if you wanted to use a library this, [`safe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe-0.3.15/docs/Safe-Exact.html#v:zipWithExactMay) would be a nice choice to turn this into a one-liner.

```
import Safe.Exact

example xs ys = fmap sum (zipWithExactMay (*) xs ys)
```

Comment: Why do you get Just 11 and not Just 10 in the first example?

Comment: @Soldalma because it is calculating (1*3)+(2*4).

Comment: Ok, got it. I am still not familiar with Haskell's syntax in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but your recursive call to `example xs ls` returns a `Maybe Int`, and you can't add an `Int` and a `Maybe Int` (in `x*l + example xs ls`), hence your error on the last line.

You can use [`fromMaybe`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=fromMaybe) to deal with this case, using `0` as the default sum:

```
example :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Maybe Int
example [] []         = Nothing
example (x:xs) (l:ls) = Just $ x * l + fromMaybe 0 (example xs ls)
```

Alternatively (and more neatly), you can avoid the explicit recursion using something like this:

```
example [] [] = Nothing
example xl yl = Just $ sum $ zipWith (*) xl yl
```

---

Note that you have non-exhaustive patterns in your pattern match. Two lists of different lengths will cause a pattern-match exception.

Comment: The recursive solution will always return `Nothing`, since it eventually reaches the empty-list-case.